# How to get result from method in other page - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, response, subscribe

I have a service.ts file where I have a function that updates a flag:

service.ts

```
setReconciliationFlag(id: string, subPostingId: string, isReconciled: string) {
    const requests = this.bmlService.get(BmlRequest.SetReconciled, {
        bwtxnid: id,
        bwpostingid: subPostingId,
        isreconciled: isReconciled,
    });
    requests.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
        (response) => {
            if (response && response.success) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return throwError({ message: response.error });
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            return throwError({ message: error });
        }
    );
}
```

Then in the component.ts I am calling this method:

```
setReconciliationFlag(id: string, subPostingId: string, isReconciled: string) {
    this.transactionHistoryStatementService.setReconciliationFlag(
        id,
        subPostingId,
        isReconciled
    );
}
```

Which is working, the method get calls and the flag gets updated but how do you return the response back to the component? If I use `then` or `subscribe` or `pipe` I get the error `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Subject in the service to emit new values and subscribe to it as an Observable from the component to receive the changes.

In this article there is a brief example (point 3): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-component-communication

P.S. Remember to unsubscribe in the component ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 0):

You should not subscribe in service and neither is your function in service returning any response. You may either return a Promise or Observable depending on your use case.

```
setReconciliationFlag(id: string, subPostingId: string, isReconciled: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.bmlService.get(BmlRequest.SetReconciled, {
        bwtxnid: id,
        bwpostingid: subPostingId,
        isreconciled: isReconciled,
    }).pipe(take(1)).toPromise().then(response => {
        if (response && response.success) return response;
        else throw new Error({ message: response.error });
    }).catch(error => {
        throw new Error({ message: error });
    });
}
```

In component,

```
setReconciliationFlag(id: string, subPostingId: string, isReconciled: string) {
    this.transactionHistoryStatementService.setReconciliationFlag(id, subPostingId, isReconciled).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```